# Implementing Web Form to collect data but users must authenticate first

Tags: web-access, cloud-deploy, authentication

I’m trying to implement a web form to collect data into a databin, but I need users authenticate first (nothing fancy, predefined usernames and password are fine), so I could collect every user data. I think `CloudDeploy[FormFunction[…]]` is enough for create the form, but I can’t get the authentication part in which if username and passwords don’t match you need to try again until they match and the form is displayed to enter your data. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to modify the permissions to ask a password before accessing to a Form.

```
CloudDeploy[FormFunction[
  {"data" -> "String"},
  Identity
  ],
 Permissions -> {PermissionsKey["TheKey"] -> "Execute"}
 ]
```

You can deploy the previous code, paste the deployed URL into a new incognito window and see that it will ask you for a password, in this case the password is `TheKey`. By default, you will have full access to the Form, but anyone else will see the prompt asking for a password.